# cual es el error que estoy omitiendo?

Tags: javascript

El planteo del arreglo es correcto?
Este seria el planteo.
El método debe retornar un arreglo con sólo las actividades de las mascotas, por ejemplo:

```
    [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]  
    
    mascotas.getActividades() 
      // debería devolver 
    ['salir a caminar, 'baño']
```

Mi código:

```
    getActividades() {       
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            actividades[i].actividad;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            actividades[i].frecuencia;
        }
        return ( actividades[i].actividad + actividades[i].frecuencia);  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El error en tu código es que retornas una sola activiadad, que sería siempre la última. Además, no tiene sentido recorrer 2 veces el array cuando la operación puede realizarse con 1 solo ciclo `for`

Lo correcto, según lo que te piden, sería:

```js
function getActividades(array) {
   let arrayActividades = []
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arrayActividades.push(actividades[i].actividad);
    }
    return arrayActividades;  
}

const actividades = [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]


console.log(getActividades(actividades))
```

El código tiene una función que recibe como parámetro un arreglo de actividades y retorna un arreglo que contiene las actividades de cada objeto presente en el arreglo de entrada.

Una forma más simple de escribir esto es usando el método `map` que devuelve un nuevo array. Este método recibe una función cómo parámetro y el resultado de esa función es lo que se añadirá al array resultante.

```js
function getActividades(actividades){
    return actividades.map(actividad => actividad.actividad)
}

const actividades = [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]

console.log(getActividades(actividades))
```

Si quieres obtener tanto la actividad como la frecuencia lo único que debes hacer es concatenar los atributos, así:

```js
function getActividades(actividades){
    return actividades.map(actividad => actividad.actividad + ' ' + actividad.frecuencia)
    // tambien puedes usar los bacticks
    // return actividades.map(actividad => `${actividad.actividad} ${ actividad.frecuencia}`)
}

const actividades = [{actividad: 'salir a caminar', frecuencia: '1 vez al dia'}, {actividad: 'baño', frecuencia: '1 vez al mes'}]

console.log(getActividades(actividades))
```